# Passing onTap function to another widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My idea is to implement `_buildTile` widget that when tapped will redirect me to another screen called `Booking`, but the function isn't working properly, as it won't redirect to the desired Booking screen.

Can someone point out where I went wrong?

```
Widget _buildTile(Widget child, {Function() onTap}) {
    return Material(
        elevation: 14.0,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
        child: InkWell(
            // Do onTap() if it isn't null, otherwise do print()
            onTap: onTap != null
                ? () => onTap()
                : () {
                    print('Not set yet');
                  },
            child: child));
  }
```

```
_buildTile(
    Padding(..), 
    onTap: (){
        new MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => BookingScreen(
                                 uid: cabId,))
           })
```

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer:**

```dart
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => YourPage(value: 0)));
```

---

**Long answer:**

You weren't using `Navigator`. Use this:

```
_buildTile(
  Padding(...),
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BookingScreen(uid:cabId)));
  },
);
```